# Intel Fortran error #10001

Tags: 12.04, intel, fortran

I have a problem with the Intel Fortran compiler.
It has been working fine in 8.04 and 10.04 LTS (well, some changes required during the installation due to the fact that 10.04 uses `dash` and not `bash` as the shell `/bin/sh`)

Now I have upgraded to 12.04 and when compiling I get the following message:

```
ifort: error #10001: could not find directory in which g++ resides
```

Is there anybody that knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have g++ installed?

Answer (score 1):

I had the some problem and it was solved using this command
`export LC_ALL=C`

It is related with the language of my OS.